# Can I use a undertow-handlers.conf file in quarkus Keycloak 20?

Tags: keycloak

I need to do some URL rewriting and such. I see [quarkus supports this](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#undertow-handlers-conf), "This file should be placed in the META-INF directory of your application jar."

But there is no reasonable way to put the undertow-handlers.conf file into the Keycloak jar.

I read the Keycloak guides, no solution provided.